# ¿Como eliminar los datos de un array de arrays, comparandolo con otro array de arrays?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola a todos en esta ocasión acudo a ustedes para pedirles consejos acerca de mi problema tengo dos array de arrays es decir un array que contiene otros arrays en el primer array tengo los valores originales y en el segundo los que quiero eliminar del array original, estos valores pueden variar y pueden tener diferentes tamaños les comparto un ejemplo de mi código para poder explicarme mejor.
Este es el array original:

```
data = [
          ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos'],
          [1, 'Darinel', 'Cigarroa'],
          [2, 'Diana', 'Rojas'],
          [3, 'Sandy','Yemell'],
          [4, 'Emiliano', 'Silva'],
          [5, 'Derky', 'Wilner']
      ];
```

Y este es el array donde guardo los elementos que quiero eliminar del array original:

```
modifiableData = [
          ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos'],
          [2, 'Diana', 'Rojas'],
          [3, 'Sandy','Yemell'],
      ];
```

También quiero eliminar el primer elemento del segundo array ya que no quiero eliminar ese array de mi arreglo original es decir este array:

```
 ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos'],
```

Normalmente suelo dejar ejemplos de mis intento e investigaciones pero esta vez no sé por donde empezar he intentado eliminar el primer elemento para no afectar mi array original con shit pero solo elimina el primer elemento de mí array y se me ocurre un filter donde me devuelva todos los valores que sean diferentes al segundo array pero igual en mis pruebas no he conseguido nada relevante, cualquier opinión o enlace a algún ejemplo sé los agradecería bastante, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Quieres que los elementos se eliminen del original, cuando alguno coincida? o deben coincidir todos los elementos para que se desencadene la eliminación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es la siguiente:

```
data = [
  ["id", "nombre", "apellidos"],
  [1, "Darinel", "Cigarroa"],
  [2, "Diana", "Rojas"],
  [3, "Sandy", "Yemell"],
  [4, "Emiliano", "Silva"],
  [5, "Derky", "Wilner"],
];

modifiableData = [
  ["id", "nombre", "apellidos"],
  [2, "Diana", "Rojas"],
  [3, "Sandy", "Yemell"],
];

for (let i = 1; i < modifiableData.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[j][0] === modifiableData[i][0]) {
      data.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
}
console.log(data)
```

Por cada elemento de modifiableData verifico si su id es igual a alguno de los id de todos los elementos del array Data, en caso de ser igual, elimino esa posición del array Data, es decir el array completo de una persona que está presente en la otra lista. Para evitar borrar los títulos de las columnas, lo que hago es en ambos casos recorrer empezando desde la posición 1 de ambos array, ya que la primer posición es 0, entonces no tiene en cuenta la comparación de los títulos. Espero te sirva.

Se podría llegar a inventar algo con algún map y/o un filter capaz, pero el for nos permite hacer eso de pasar por alto la primer posición que es la de los títulos facilmente.

---

Para evitar modificar el original, podrías generar una copia del array Data y trabajar sobre la copia en comparación con modifiable. Quedaría algo así, al final hago console.log del resultado de copia ya modificado y del original para verificar que no fue afectado.

```
const data = [
  ["id", "nombre", "apellidos"],
  [1, "Darinel", "Cigarroa"],
  [2, "Diana", "Rojas"],
  [3, "Sandy", "Yemell"],
  [4, "Emiliano", "Silva"],
  [5, "Derky", "Wilner"],
];

const copyOfData = [...data];

const modifiableData = [
  ["id", "nombre", "apellidos"],
  [2, "Diana", "Rojas"],
  [3, "Sandy", "Yemell"],
];

for (let i = 1; i < modifiableData.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < copyOfData.length; j++) {
    if (copyOfData[j][0] === modifiableData[i][0]) {
      copyOfData.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
}
console.log("Copia modificada", copyOfData);
console.log("Original", data);
```